# When I page to the right using UIScrollview within my UICollectionViewCell, it also scrolls in every fourth cell from that cell, up and down

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I page to the right using UIScrollview within my UITableViewCell, it also scrolls in every fourth cell from that cell, up and down.

It is creating the scroll view based on a property within the containing view, contained by a UITableViewCell.

the only method the scrollview has is

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(UIScollView *)scrollView{
    scrollview.contentoffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width,0);
}
```

Basically every time a new cell is drawn, it takes the scroll position of the cell that has just been undrawn.

Is there any work around for this besides disabling deque?  I mean, I'd like to be able to scroll down and then scroll back up without affecting the horizontal scroll within the cell.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your cells, which are reused/dequeued, aren't being reset.

When you dequeue and configure your cells you need to include logic to set as well as reset, something like this:

```
if (isCustom) {
    [cell setupAsCustom];
} else {
    [cell setupAsDefault];
}
```

As opposed to just this:

```
if (isCustom) {
    [cell setupAsCustom];
}
```

In this case the `customness` of the cell is its `contentOffset`. Hope this helps.